# Is it possible to add a behavior of Scroll Rect and Horizontal Layout Group components to non-UI object?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I need to make a container on the screen that can be scrolled with a swipe on mobile devices, and which contains elements with Transform in it (RectTransform is not suitable for certain reasons). At the same time, such elements should be evenly distributed in the parent container.

Therefore, I need container behavior with Scroll Rect and Horizontal Layout Group components, but which works with Transform components.

Is it possible to do this in Unity?

Comment: Yes Unity games support swiping.  Exactly what happens is up to you

Comment: If you can't use scroll rect you'd have to make your own but it's simple enough. Make an equivalent out of game objects or whatever you want to use. Check out https://docs.unity3d.com/2018.4/Documentation/ScriptReference/EventSystems.IPointerEnterHandler.html and the other `IPointer` interfaces then use that input data to move the elements of your custom scroll rect.